# How can I apply Angular and UI-Sortable with to table cells without awkward spacing?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-sortable

I want a table sortable by column using Angular UI-Sortable. When there are multiple rows in the table, the spacing gets confused. I think this is because the dragged cell and the placeholder are taking up space, even though the dragged cell is absolutely positioned.

My table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr ui-sortable="{'ui-floating': true, axis: 'x'}" ng-model="list">
        <th ng-repeat="item in list">
          {{item.text}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="item in list">
          {{item.text}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('sortableApp', ['ui.sortable']);

myapp.controller('sortableController', function($scope) {
  var tmpList = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    tmpList.push({
      text: 'Item ' + i,
      value: i
    });
  }

  $scope.list = tmpList;
});
```

I also have an [example on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyXWEQ). Try dragging the first cell to see the rest of the row shift down past the end of the table.

I'm running `Angular v1.4.9` and `angular-ui-sortable v0.14.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. By adding an empty cell to each row, and adding `ng-show` to the first one, I get a cell to remove when the placeholder is added. This works pretty well, but the empty cell does take up a little space, and it makes the html a little less clear.

Updated codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPZBxq